# Error in Core language used by PhpStorm for exception and others

Tags: phpstorm, php-7, phpstorm-2018.1

I have an error when define PHP version in 5.6 on settings.

PhpStorm, in 2018.1.6 version, use Core with PHP 7 and logically use PHP 7 implementations. By example for extends Exception, PhpStorm create an constructor with a third parameter has an instance of `Throwable`.

It's very problematic, do you have an idea for solve this problem?

Following the answers, for reproduce, please follow this steps :

- using PHPStorm 2018.1.6
- create an TestException extends \Exception
- create a constructor with autocompletion

PHPStorm extends a PHP 7 version of \Exception and not a PHP 5.6 version of Exception, PHP 7 version integration Throwable interface for previous exception but not PHP 5.6 version.

Use autocomplete function to create constructor:

[image: Use autocomplete function to create constructor]

Constructor implements throwable interface for previous exception:

[image: Constructor implements throwable interface for previous exception]

Comment: *I have an error* - what error?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and include a short code sample and the exact steps to reproduce the issue? PhpStorm automates code generation in several different places and it's unclear which one you mean (or at least I can't figure it out).

Comment: I modify my question for integrate a steps for reproduce

Comment: I guess you mean that you already have the class and then use the "Generate constructor" feature. I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce it. [This is what I get](https://i.imgur.com/t0zYjbF.png).

Comment: I update my initial message with two screenshoots

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having `Throwable` type hint for `$previous` at third argument of `Exception` constructor. This is the correct signature for PHP 7 code. What is your problem with `Throwable` there?